# ./src/App.js 83:48-54 "export 'default' (imported as 'Signup') was not found in './Signup.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am not understood Please need help. I am new at react.

Here is my code.

```
App.js
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Signup from './Signup.js';
import Login from './Login.js';

class App extends Component {

  getInitialState(){
    return {signup:false,login:true}
  }

  switch(word){
    var signup,login;
    if(word == "signup"){signup = true;login = false;}
    else{login = true; signup = false;}
    return this.setState({login:login,signup:signup})    
  }

  render(){    //this is render method
    var self = this;
      return (
        <div>
          <div id="buttons">
            <p id="signupButton" onClick={self.switch.bind(null,"signup")} className={self.state.signup ? "yellow":"blue"}>Sign In</p>
            <p id="loginButton" onClick={self.switch.bind(null,"login")} className={self.state.login ? "yellow":"blue"}> Login</p>
          </div>              
            {self.state.signup? <Signup/> : null}
            {self.state.login? <Login /> : null}            
        </div>
            )
  }
}

export default App; // I think problem is here but not understood
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

here is my login.js page code
    login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Login extends Component {
    render(){
            return (
                 <div>
                    <div id="login">
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                        <button id="send">Send</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            )
      }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is my Signup.js page code
    Signup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Signup extends Component {

  render(){
         return (
            <div>
                  <div id="signup">
                        <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="First Name"/>
                        <input type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <input type="password" id="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                    <button id="send">Send</button>
            </div>
                </div>

            )
      }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

where is the problem I m not understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it possible for import you need to export your class first:

```
export default class Signup extends Component {
```

in Signup.js and and in login.js:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your classes first.

For example `Signup`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Signup extends Component {

  render(){
         return (
            <div>
                  <div id="signup">
                        <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="First Name"/>
                        <input type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <input type="password" id="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                    <button id="send">Send</button>
            </div>
                </div>

            )
      }
}

export default Signup;
```

Now the `Signup` class is exported as a default export.

In your `App.js` you can import it via `import Signup from './Signup';`

You should read more about ES6 modules first.

http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html